# Creating Kernel Module

Tags: linux-kernel, make, c

I am currently reading a book on Linux Kernel Module Programming - https://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/lkmpg.pdf and I am running into a compilation error when running make.

```
/*  hello.c − The simplest kernel module.
 *
 */
/* Kernel Programming */

#define MODULE
#define LINUX
#define __KERNEL__

#include <linux/module.h>  /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>  /* Needed for KERN_ALERT */

int init_module(void)
{
   printk("<1>Hello world 1.\n");
   // A non 0 return means init_module failed; module can't be loaded.
   return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

```
TARGET  := hello
WARN    := −W −Wall −Wstrict−prototypes −Wmissing−prototypes
INCLUDE := −isystem /lib/modules/`uname −r` /build/include
CFLAGS  := −O2 −DMODULE −D__KERNEL__ ${WARN} ${INCLUDE}
CC      := gcc

${TARGET}.o: ${TARGET}.c

.PHONY: clean

clean: rm −rf ${TARGET}.o
```

```
gcc −O2 −DMODULE −D__KERNEL__ −W −Wall −Wstrict−prototypes −Wmissing−prototypes −isystem /lib/modules/`uname −r` /build/include   -c -o hello.o hello.c
uname: extra operand ‘−r’
Try 'uname --help' for more information.
gcc: error: −O2: No such file or directory
gcc: error: −DMODULE: No such file or directory
gcc: error: −D__KERNEL__: No such file or directory
gcc: error: −W: No such file or directory
gcc: error: −Wall: No such file or directory
gcc: error: −Wstrict−prototypes: No such file or directory
gcc: error: −Wmissing−prototypes: No such file or directory
gcc: error: −isystem: No such file or directory
gcc: error: /build/include: No such file or directory
make: *** [<builtin>: hello.o] Error 1
```

The errors that i receive are command options defined in the Makefile. What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use hyphens, `-`, not en-dashes, `−`.

You also need to remove the extra space in

```
INCLUDE := -isystem /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/include
```

(just before `/build/include`).

Comment: Thank you for that. I initially wrote the code in a terminal then when I opened the source code in text editor I seen the formatting differences. But I am still getting a `gcc: error: /build/include: No such file or directory`

Comment: See the update.